# Why are 5 Volt 7-8 Amps chargers not available for charging phones quickly?

Tags: battery-charging, charger, lithium-ion

Available phone s chargers have either 0.5, 1, 2 Amps rating depending on the batteries (varied capacity) used. Why is it that 7, 8 Amps chargers are not available ?
if the limitation is in the **Lithium Ion** batteries we use... then what's the maximum possible current to charge them without damaging.... to design a portable **charger for phones**.

Comment: This is not a usage question.  Rather, it asks what **engineering limitations** drive the availability of a hypothetically product.

Comment: I think this is a good question with a good answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lithium-ion cells can be made to handle charging rates of up to 5 times their capacity, so theoretically you could charge a 1600mAh battery at 8A. However its lifespan may be reduced, and the chances of something going wrong and causing a fire are greater. All the associated circuitry in the phone (including charge controller, battery protection circuit, wiring, connectors) would have to be beefed up to handle the higher current safely. That is bound to make the phone (and its power supply) bulkier, heavier, and more expensive.

The other problem is that it wouldn't charge that much faster anyway. The battery's internal resistance limits how long it can be charged for at maximum rate. Topping off then takes almost as long as it would at a lower rate. So while you might think that at 8A your 1600mAh battery would reach full charge in just 12 minutes, in practice it might take 30 minutes or more.

Also, as a Lithium-ion battery ages its internal resistance increases, causing it to reach peak voltage sooner and take longer to charge. So to keep getting the faster charging time the battery would have to be replaced more often. That is a recipe for customer dissatisfaction.

Comment: Someone in a hurry might not care about "topping off" but merely getting a useful amount of charge into the device in a short period of time.  But few "phones" are going to have 1600mAh internal packs.

Comment: Battery capacities are increasing. The iPhone 5S has a 1560mAh battery. The iPhone 6 is 1800mAh (I hear Apple has sold a "few" of them). The iPhone 6 Plus is 2900mAh...